# jQuery .data() does not work if i call my external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In my wp website i need to call within my `<head>` tag an external js script for tracking visitors behavior on site but if i include that script at every time i load page browser return

"Error reading the response: TypeError: undefined is not a function"

and when i debug code i see the error in a js internal wp file on a line like

```
options = jQuery(this).data('settings');
```

If i remove my external script all works done.
Now, how is possible for an externarl script disable the use of jQuery .data function?
The script is mine and i don't understand how this is possible.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance
AM

Comment: its jQuery and not jquery

Comment: Yes sorry the correct line when i see the error is "options = jQuery(this).data('settings');"

Comment: what `this` represents in that line? Also could you please share your external script code?

Comment: Sorry but the line of code i have mentioned is referred at an internal js wordpress file, it isn't a line of mine.

Comment: When i don't include my external script all works done, but when in the head of website i include my js there is an error "TypeError: undefined is not a function" on that line

Comment: Can you post the your external js code. Partial of that part.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
options = jQuery(this).attr('data-settings');
```

if this doen't work try to debug it with:

```
console.log(jQuery(this));
```

and you will be able to trace the problem

Comment: Hi thanks but i can't modify, that file is a wp one.

Comment: you can still paste bigger snippet of the code, just with one line it's impossible to help..

Comment: I can only modify my script but i don't understand where is the problem because the only error returned is on that line and not on my js

Comment: showing code = solved problem...what to tell you more :)

Comment: It's an huge code than call many functions, i can't post all. I just wanted to know if there was any particular function that could create problems of interaction with jQuery.data

Comment: not really. the error says that you either include jQuery after your external code OR jQuery(this) is undefined. I think the first reason is in your case, but I just guess, because without code snippet I'm blind